# Laravel 9 report() with context

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I would like to log context of exception as current data in some variables. But repost() handler which I use to log exceptions does not support context parameters. Is there any other way to do it?

```php
try {  
   // process the points
   $customerPointsService->subtractPointsForRewardReservation($customerReward);
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
   report($e);  
   // I would like to log also some variable values
   return $this->sendJsonErrorWithCorrectStatusCode("Customer point subtraction failed.", [], 422);
}
```

Comment: just above the report($e)  , add  Log::error('Customer point subtraction failed.', ['customer_reward_id' => $customerReward->id]);

Comment: You mean to use both? Log::error should be enough. Shouldnt be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom exception:

```
class ContextualException extends \Exception {
    protected $context;

    public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, Throwable $previous = null, $context = []) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getContext() {
        return $this->context;
    }
}
```

```
try {
    // If an error occurs
    throw new ContextualException("Error message", 0, null, ['variable' => $variableValue]);
} catch (ContextualException $e) {
    report($e);
    // Access context data
    $context = $e->getContext();
    // Log context or do something with it
    return $this->sendJsonErrorWithCorrectStatusCode("Customer point subtraction failed.", [], 422);
}
```